# Do all AutoCAD DXF files have an origin in San Francisco?

Tags: coordinate-system, dxf, autocad, autodesk

I have a DXF file representing a suburb under construction in Western Australia. However, the file contains the following:

```
$LATITUDE
 40
37.795
  9
$LONGITUDE
 40
-122.394
  9
```

This location is a point in downtown San Francisco, USA.

Is this a peculiarity of DXF files exported from AutoCAD (with its Word Coordinate System), or is this just an error in this particular file?

Comment: No, most CAD files start a 0.0 or offset from 0,0. Would contact the people who sent you the file and confirm.